# Dynammically Updating sharepoint announcements using data of sharepoint list in same web page?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have **Web page in share-point 2010**,its has **two web parts one for announcements** at top and **one is a list** which will be used by many people u can say hardware inventory list..so basically what my requirement is that **when any item in list is updated that should be reflected back in the announcements** ,it can be **like last 5 items edited** which i can show in announcements,that would help other users about recent updates to the list,can i do it non- programatically using any in-build feature of sharepoint2010 or i need to go to any programming approach.....one more thing i want to implement **is it possible to enforce check-out check-in option for this page**,i see that users can directly update list webpart data without explictly checkin- out and in of the  page ,not sure if this can be possible in sharepoint 2010

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future remember to post a separate question for every problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** Instead of the announcements, add second Web Part showing items from the hardware inventory list and configure it to use a view that shows 5 items sorted by the *Modified* date.

**Q2:** [Enable versioning](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/how-does-versioning-work-in-a-list-or-library-HA101852686.aspx) for the hardware inventory list.

Comment: This is Awesome,oh god how come i landed in such a awesome website with awesome people ,thanks a lot... :)